# Regex is capturing too much of the string

Tags: javascript, regex

I have these three regex statements and I'm using `Javascript`

```
/(?<=[AND])\s?\[(.*?)\]/
/(?<=[OR])\s?\[(.*?)\]/
/(?<=[NOT])\s?\[(.*?)\]/
```

given a string like -> `AND [thing1, thing2, thing3] OR [thing4, thing5] NOT [thing6]` I would expect the matches for the patterns to return in order

```
thing1, thing2, thing3
thing4, thing5
thing6
```

When a user enters a string like this -> `AND [thing1, thing2, thing3 OR [thing4, thing5]`
the first pattern returns

```
thing1, thing2, thing3 OR [thing4, thing5
```

I'm trying to figure out how to prevent the regex from matching when there is a boolean keyword present before a closing bracket.  I've tried messing around with adding `[^NOT]|[^OR] ^NOT|^OR` in the   capturing group but nothing I've done works right (regex newb here).

Also if there are any other potentially obvious mistakes with my current regex you see please point them out.

Edit: Sorry everyone for the slow response, it took me a little while to decipher what your regexes are doing. Thank you for the info about the brackets being capturing groups, I see what I was doing wrong beforehand.

Comment: In the case of the malformed input, what do you want the regex to do?  Should it capture `thing1, thing2, thing3` despite the missing `]`, or should it skip that part and just match `OR [thing4, thing5]` , or should it fail completely?

Comment: In this case I would like it to fail completely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not combine each of these patterns into a single matching group? You seem to have some fundamental misconceptions, specifically regarding the use of square brackets (`[]`) in your pattern.

It's not clear why you've elected to include your logical tokens in these square brackets - in RegExp, these are used specifically to denotate *character sets*. The way you've expressed this in your original pattern matches one of the two or three characters in the set literally, and not the entire word (as appears to be your intention). You also seem to have fallen victim to the same misconception in your attempt to include these logical tokens in the last group in your pattern.

Instead, use alternatives (denotated by vertical pipes `|`) correctly:

```js
const test1 = `AND [thing1, thing2, thing3] OR [thing4, thing5] NOT [thing6]`;
const test2 = `AND [thing1, thing2, thing3 OR [thing4, thing5]`;

const pattern = /(?<=AND|OR|NOT)(?:\s?)\[(.*?)(?:\]|\s(AND|OR|NOT))/g;

console.log([...test1.matchAll(pattern)].map(match => match[1]));
console.log([...test2.matchAll(pattern)].map(match => match[1]));
```

[<sup>regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/TD3nCU/1)

Since you're new to JavaScript, I'd recommend using a utility like [regex101](https://regex101.com) to build your patterns - by default, a pane in the right-hand side of the window explains, in plain English, what each part of your pattern *actually* does, which you can compare to what you *expect* it to do and adjust accordingly.

Comment: this is great!  The reason I had them in separate statements is that I'm doing other validation beforehand with AND OR NOT individually.  Then after I capture what's in the brackets I need to know if that info came from AND, OR, NOT and there was no other way I could figure out to do that.

Comment: If you need to know *which* logical operator precedes the match, you might consider changing your initial lookbehind to a capturing group and reading the matched value in JavaScript and performing the associated logic there - much more efficient that way.

Comment: Ahhh, yes that would be a way better solution!

Answer (score 0):

- Using `[AND]` means a character class, and matches a single character `A` `N` `D`
- Using `[^NOT]` means a negated character class matching any single char except `N` `O` `T`
- Using `^NOT|^OR` means matching either NOT or OR at the start of the string

If you want to 3 alternatives, you can do so using an alternation in a group `(?:AND|OR|NOT)`

Using Javascript, you might assert that between the opening and the closing square bracket there is no AND OR NOT

```
(?<=(?:AND|OR|NOT)\s?\[)(?![^\][]*\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b)[^\][]*(?=\])
```

- `(?<=(?:AND|OR|NOT)\s?\[)` Positive lookbehind, assert any of the alternatives to the left
- `(?![^\][]*\b(?:AND|OR|NOT)\b)` Negative lookahead to assert not any of the alternatives before any of the square brackets
- `[^\][]*` Match optional chars other than `[` and `]`
- `(?=\])` Positive lookahead, assert `]` to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/sCt2fL/1)